# Chain multiple POST requests together using AJAX and jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery

I received a suggestion from a prior question that I need to amend my code **chain** a series of POST requests together, but I don't have any idea how to accomplish this.  Specifically, the advice I was given was to:

> fire off a post, have its success handler fire off the next post,
>   etc... and then when all the posts are done, the final post's success
>   handler fires off the get

This strategy makes sense to me but I do not know how to implement.  I am trying to prevent the call to GET before all of the calls to POST have completed. Currently, I have implemented `$.when.apply` to delay the sending of GET. Here is the code for that:

```
function(){ 
$.when.apply(undefined, InsertTheAPPs()).done(function () {
$.ajax({
url: sURL + "fileappeal/send_apps_email",
success: function() {  
    var m = $.msg("my message",
    {header:'my header', live:10000});
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(m)m.setBody('...my other message.');             
    },3000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(m)m.close(function(){
              window.location.replace(sURL+'client/view');
        });
    },6000);
    $('#ajaxShield').fadeOut(1000);},
error: function(){
    $.msg("error message",
    {header:'error header', live:10000});
    }
}); 
}); 
}
```

Here is the code for the jQuery $.each loop. This is the code that needs to not only begin, but must end before the ajax call to fileappeal/send_apps_email above:

```
function InsertTheAPPs(){
$('input[name=c_maybe].c_box').each(function(){         
    var jqxhrs = [];
    if($(this).prop('checked')){ 
        var rn = $(this).prop('value'); 
        jqxhrs.push(
            $.ajax({
            url: sURL + 'fileappeal/insert_app',
            type:"POST",
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {'rn': rn},
            error: function(data) {console.log('Error:'+rn+'_'+data);}
            })
        )
    return jqxhrs;
    } 
}); 
}
```

Could someone demonstrate how I can modify the code above to implement the strategy of chaining together the multiple POST calls?

Comment: You have the `return jqxhrs` inside the each so it is never retruned.

Comment: Pass the result of each successful call to the .done() of the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't return from `.each`.  It doesn't work that way.  Instead do this:

```
var jqxhrs = [];
$(...).each(...
});
return jqxhrs;
```

Nothing is assigned to the return value of `.each`, which you can't get anyway.  Returning from each allows it to be used like break/continue, which doesn't make sense in your context.

Moreover, the `var jqxhrs` inside of the each loop causes a new variable to be declared in that context on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Thanks so much Explosion Pills, you have solved my problem.  If we were in the same city I would take you to a great lunch to thank you.  Instead you are going to have to settle for my heartfelt gratitude.  You truly are a Software developer extraordinaire!

Comment: @DanielAttard I only say that in my profile as a show of mock-arrogance, but I appreciate the sentiment

Comment: If the shoe fits...  Thanks again.